# Finding the path from a list of adjacency information

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph, path

I have data in database which is in the form of:

```
A -> B
C -> D
B -> C
F -> G
G -> J
X -> Z
```

This basically means that A goes to B, C goes to D etc. Given this data and a node (such as C) I would like to construct the *complete* path that C is found that is A -> B -> C -> D . I tried to do this by using a few dictionaries and recursive loops but I don't like such a sluggish solution since there are lots of data in db. What is a better way to solve this problem ? In terms of both algorithm and the data structure ? Any ideas or hints are appreciated.

Comment: "The" complete path? There may be multiple complete paths. Or no complete path.

Comment: The "complete path" is a [*Hamiltonian Path*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path)? If so- you are facing an NP-Complete problem known as the [Hamiltonian Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem), and there is no known polynomial solution to it

Comment: @CédricBignon By complete path I mean the path before and after C. There is always a path that can be constructed from the data and there cannot be be multiple paths (due to the definition of the structure)

Comment: @amit it's not a hamiltonian path. The path is directed and it doesnt have to pass from all vertices

Comment: Then I don't understand the problem, please better describe it.

Comment: @amit I have some adjacency info in db (see edit for update). For example the user will select node C. I need to show him both the path coming to C and the path going from C that is A -> B -> C -> D. Basically the question is given C and that data how would you form the path  "A -> B -> C -> D" ?

Comment: So you have no branches (e.g. `C->E` wouldn't be a valid addition to your input)?

Comment: @Rawling No there is no branches so C -> E is not a valid addition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking basically for [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), but you need to do it twice - one per direction.

First do a a DFS on the reverse 'graph', starting from C. 

In your example it will give you `Path1 = C->B->A`

Next, do a DFS on the original graph, again from C.

In your example it will give you `Path2= C->D`

Now, by reversing `Path1`, and concatinating `Path2` to it you will get:

```
reverse(Path1)  + Path2 = A->B->C + C->D = A->B->C->D
```

---

Clarification - DFS is just abstraction, what you actually are doing is something similar to (pseudo code):

```
current <- C
list = []
while (current != null):
   list.addFirst(current)
   current <- u such that (u,current) is in the DataBase
current <- C
list.deleteLast() // last is C
while (current != null):
   list.addLast(current)
   current <- u such that (current,u) is in the DataBase
```

Note that finding `u` both cases is a simple dictionary look up, in the first the "Target" is the key, and in the second the "Source" is the key.